# AWS Elasticsearch C# SDK AWSSDK.Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am using AWSSDK.Elasticsearch for connecting and working with AWS Elasticsearch in .net.
I am able to connect to Elasticsearch.
But how can I post data to an index in ES domain using "AWSSDK.Elasticsearch" this package.
I didn't find any method in "AWSSDK.Elasticsearch" this package to do posting data.
Please help.